# Create Generic Method to handle multiple datatypes

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

`

```
  protected ValidationResult IsValid(
            ISafeModule SafeModule,
            NameAttribute propertyAttribute,
            ILanguageService languageService,
            object value)
{

  if (!SafeModule.MetaData.TryGetParameter(
                    propertyAttribute.Name,
                    out IFParameter**<ushort>** parameterMetaData))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }

 return ValidateParameter((**ushort**)value, propertyAttribute, languageService);
}`
```

where

```
 public static bool TryGetParameter<T>(
            this IDataItem fParameter,
            string Name,
            out IParameter<T> parameter) where T : IComparable<T>
        {}
and


protected ValidationResult ValidateParameter<T>(
        T value,
        IFParameter<T> Parameter,
        ILanguageService languageService) where T : IComparable<T>
    {}
```

in this code base , i need to handle not only ushort  but int , float, etc.. data types.
Which i need some insights to handle the multiple data types.

Highly appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: I can't help but feel that a generic class that uses _reflection_ is just as bad a design as a generic class that attempts to cast generic parameters to other concrete types and perform conditional processing with said type.   It's like a method that takes an interface as an argument then proceeds to cast it to a concrete type breaking abstractions in the process. e.g. `public void DoSomething (ISomeInterface something) { if (something is SomethingElse x) { ... } else if (something is SomeOtherSomething y) { ... } }`

Comment: There is no good solution to this problem. That's why .NET 7 is adding new interfaces that, for instance, all numeric types will implement. Then you will be able to constrain a generic type parameter to be, for instance, `INumber` and access functionality of that interface. For now, you're just going to have to overload your method(s), just as is already done in .NET when the same functionality is required for multiple numeric types.